# Is it more efficient to implement `operator==()` with `operator!=()` or vice-versa?

Tags: c++

It seems to me that for any composite object, it is inefficient to implement `operator!=` in terms of `operator==`.
For an object with `N` subobjects to compare, `operator==` must *always* perform every one of those comparisons: 2 objects are equal if and only if every sub-object is equal. (Ignoring irrelevant sub-objects for this discussion.)

Compare to `operator!=`, in which it is sufficient to check sub-objects only until a mismatch is found. To make `operator!=` delegate to `operator==` is therefore inefficient in the composite case, as it yields N comparisons in *every* case, instead of just the worst case.

This is posted as a new question after an overlong comment discussion started by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000530/does-overloading-get-you/8000542?noredirect=1#comment66757862_8000542). The other commenter stated:

> `operator==` does not always require N comparisons, it only requires N comparisons in the worst case, which is when at least all but the last subobjects are equal

I can't see how that can possibly be correct..have I missed something?

This is of course far more general than purely C++, but since the discussion was specific to that I've kept the same tag.

Comment: You expect that `operator==` returns `true`. But it can also return `false` and in such a case the first comparison that fails can stop the computation.

Comment: Note: an implementation like `!(this.a == other.a && this.b == other.b)` will short circut if `this.a != other.a`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation (in other words)

Comment: Short circuit break of comparison depends on probability (neither == or != is better)

Comment: I wonder why there are so many downvoters. Seems like a reasonable question to me - even if the OP's arguments don't make too much sense. But there could still be some other reason for prefering one solution over the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `==` and `!=` will stop evaluation at the first subobject not satisfying the condition. So, from a general perspective, they are equal.

`==` will evaluate to:

```
A==A0 && B==B0 && C==C0 && ....
```

and stop as soon as `A==A0` or `B==B0` or `C==C0` or .... evaluates false.

`!=` will evaluate to:

```
A!=A0 || B!=B0 || C!=C0 || ...
```

and stop as soon as `A!=A0` or `B!=B0` or `C!=C0` or .... evaluates true.

In specific cases, one may be better than the other but in general they are equal.

Comment: Thank you. My intuition had gone haywire and ignored short-circuiting for one case.

Answer (score 2):

Well the same should hold for `==`, shouldn't?

As soon as the `==` operator finds two elements that are **not** equal it can seize to compare the following elements, since the objects cannot be equal anymore.